# How to toggle Between two elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to toggle visibility between two `sections` with one button.

I have two sections one for `signin` and one for `register`.
I want the user to have the ability to switch between those sections

the initial click event works, but I couldn't figure out how to flip the click event to swap on the next click.

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id="btn">Click</button>
  <section id="register" class="active"></section>
  <section id="signup" class="hide"></section>
</div>
```

```js
  let btn = $('#btn')
  let login = $('#login');
  let register = $('#register');

  btn.on('click',(e)=>{
   e.preventDefault(); 
   register.removeClass('active').addClass('hide');
   login.removeClass('hide').addClass('active');

  })
```

Comment: Your HTML defines sections with the `id`s `register` and `signup`, but your code expects `register` and `login`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
btn.on('click',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault(); 
    register.toggleClass('active hide');
    login.toggleClass('active hide');
});
```

Provided one of them has `active` and the other has `hide` when you start, that will toggle between them.

Unless you're using `login` and `register` elsewhere in your code, you could combine them.

```
let btn = $('#btn')
let panels = $('#login, #register');
btn.on('click',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault(); 
    panels.toggleClass('active hide');
});
```

Live Example :

```js
let btn = $('#btn')
let panels = $('#login, #register');
btn.on('click',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault(); 
    panels.toggleClass('active hide');
});
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id="btn">Click</button>
  <section id="register" class="active">register</section>
  <section id="login" class="hide">login</section>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that unless you're using `active` for something else, you don't need it:

```js
let btn = $('#btn')
let panels = $('#login, #register');
btn.on('click',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault(); 
    panels.toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id="btn">Click</button>
  <section id="register">register</section>
  <section id="login" class="hide">login</section>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: Your HTML defines sections with the `id`s `register` and `signup`, but your code expects `register` and `login`. I've fixed that in the live examples above.

Comment: Thanks trying it out now. just one q, lets say I only have the hide class is it still possible ?

Comment: @Osh - Yes, and in fact I was going to mention that unless you're using `active` for something else, you don't need it.

Comment: So cool works great, a little bit confusing trying to wrap my head whats going on there, but works like a charm :)

Comment: I think I need to recreate this in vanilla to understand it , any tips ?

Comment: @Osh You mean "with the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)." `querySelectorAll`'s `NodeList` is iterable (and has `forEach`) in modern environments, and [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) has a [`toggle` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle).

Comment: yes, Im trying to wrap my head how to create this function so I can understand this method better. although its working I'm a bit confused on the events happening behind the scenes.
I was thinking if I want to change the text of the button as well how can I do that?